# Program does not come back to previous state

Tags: microcontroller

I wrote program for toroidal transformer winding , but when electricity goes off , it does not come back to previous state . It starts again from beginning. How i can save previous values of strokes so it could start again from that point , i am using atmel . Any suggestions ?

Comment: how about detecting power outage and writing the last stroke value to EEPROM before ATMEL turns off. A voltage monitoring IC can indicate MCU that, power is lost and the remaining juice in the capacitor on the board can assist the MCU to complete one EEPROM write operation.

Comment: Where i should put the capacitor ? Parallel to the Vss and Vdd of MCU ?

Comment: yes. But, you have to give more details to answer the question better. Are you running form mains. do you have any zero cross detection circuitry. Which MCU are you using? how is the power distribution. Do you have EEPROM? Once notified of power outage, how much time is required for you to safely record the last stroke into EEPROM? are there any significant load which can be isolated immediately after detecting power outage..so that MCU had enough energy to write the date to EEPROM.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Add a complete battery backed power supply (eg. Mean-Well AD-55A) - definitely the easiest.
2. Add a battery, charger and control components to your board (harder).
3. Use big capacitors, detect when power is about to be lost and save current state to EEPROM or flash.
4. Whenever you change something - immediately write it to EEPROM (you will have to do wear leveling, otherwise the memory will wear out). You can also use external EEPROM or flash with big capacity to do more wear leveling.
5. If your state is small you can use an RTC chip eg. DS1307 with a backup battery as backup RAM - the chip has 56 bytes available for any purpose. You will probably have to keep two copies of your state in that memory, so if you are updating one copy and power fails, then the other copy will stay intact. Of course come kind of CRC is a must. RAM does not have any limits on read/write cycles.